# links inside a Jquery sliding panel don't work

Tags: jquery, click, slide

iam using JQuery to create a dropdown panel
shortly i used this code

```
$('.tools-bg a.signup').click(function(e){
    $('.form-bg.signup').slideToggle(200);
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(document).click(function(){
    $('.form-bg.signup').slideUp(200);
});
```

it works fine for me but i have a smull bug , when i click a link inside the panel it slides up without going to the A tag Url

Comment: It's because of this line `$(document).click()...` I guess..

Comment: i know but i wanna slide it up when user clicks at any palce od the Document